# Can we get tag voting stats in per-user overview form?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, statistics, profile-page

So we have a tag-centric view of tag voting stats, which is great.  Can we get a user-centric view?  Something organized like:

```
              answers      questions
php             477           28
mysql           212
linux           129           48
```

It seems like it would fit as a tab in the user profile display.  It could be argued that it could replace the user tag activity block, but that block measures different statistics that are separately interesting, and this display would probably be a lot less compact than the tag activity block.

Comment: Mehrdad put something together a while back that would accumulate this data for you (.Net winforms app), but I don't have the link now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38860/how-can-i-see-how-many-upvotes-and-downvotes-i-have-per-tag/71884#71884):

> Your user page now shows your score per tag, under the tags section. Mouse over the number to get a detailed breakdown.