# Finding Reputation from Tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tags, profile-page

Very simply, I'd like to find out precisely how much reputation I've received from each tag.

As it is, I can see the **number** of tags that I've answered / asked on my profile page under the "tags" section, but what I can't tell is their relative weighting.  If I've answered 10 questions on .NET and gotten 1 upvote each, but I've answered 8 questions on Java and gotten 3 upvotes each, it seems pretty clear that my value to the community (as measured by rep) is higher for Java than it is for .NET, but there is no way of determining that from the profile page.

What I'd like to see is a way to determine just how much reputation I've received from any given tag.  Obviously, this would not add up to my total rep, since questions get tagged with multiple tags, but it WOULD give me a very good idea of where my efforts in the community are best received.  In the same way, being able to see someone else's reputation based upon the tags they have answered would allow for increasing (or decreasing, for that matter) the confidence one could have in that person's answer.

What is the feasibility of this request based upon the back end implementation?  I know that reputation can be recalculated based upon logs (I was the recipient of a negative recalculation recently), so I know the information is in there somewhere...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6153/

Comment: Not an exact duplicate: the specified question wants to have a split between questions and answers for tags; I am specifically asking for finding the reputation awarded based upon tags.  Two completely different concepts.  Note that the "duplicate" doesn't mention reputation anywhere.

Comment: this seems like a nice extension of the specialist / generalist badges and wouldn't it be nice to see that the high rep guy that you're about to take advice from has serious chops for tags related to your question? Tag specific level of trust would be cool.

Comment: @HamishSmith:  Yeah, exactly.  Knowing that the guy I'm getting an answer from has +1000 rep from the subject area would really make me feel confident in his answer; and seeing that someone had negative rep would make me really consider if they actually knew what they were saying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is effectively the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6220) - they're basically pretty similar.)

If you click on a tag and then choose the "stats" tab, it will show your personal stats for that tag as well as a leaderboard. That includes the number of answers given and the total number of votes received.

Note that that won't take account of the reputation limit (otherwise I'd have over 110,000 rep just from the C# tag!) or accepted answers, but it gives a good idea of how much the community has liked your answers. In fact, it gives a *better* impression of where your efforts are best received, as the time of day *doesn't* affect the effective value of the vote in terms of "community value" but *can* affect the value in terms of rep.

To take account of accepted answers you could use the data dump, but figuring the rep cap into it would require basically reproducing all of the logic of the engine in terms of all kinds of things.

Oh, and finally I'm not sure what it does for CW posts using that tag.

Comment: This is interesting, because I didn't know this functionality was there, but I'm not seeing any "personal" stats for the tag.

Comment: I'm reading "from each tag" to mean that he'd like a list of all the tags he has reputation for, and how much rep for each.  It would be tedious to check each one individually...more so for some than for others. ;)

Comment: @BillTheLizard: exactly; there's value in the comparative valuation.  I'd like to know what THE COMMUNITY thinks that I know a lot about, not just what I think I know a lot about.

Comment: Well pick the tags that seem likely, and just look at the personal value for each of those - shouldn't take very long.

Comment: @JonSkeet: even doing that, the information returned is of a different caliber; the information gained from this method is of the number of upvotes obtained, not the reputation (as you pointed out).  I'm really interested in knowing where my reputation comes from, not in what community wiki tags I've gotten upvoted.

Comment: You said before that you wanted a measure of what the community thinks of your input. Votes are a better measure of that than rep. In fact I don't *think* CW posts count in the vote tally for tags anyway, so that's one problem out of the way.

Comment: @Jon do you know if there is a delay on the tag stats calculation? I have hit the rep limit today and got 3 further upvotes (that I know of) for the maven tag, but my total on the stats page hasn't shifted

Comment: It looks like there is a small delay, they just appeared though.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38860/how-can-i-see-how-many-upvotes-and-downvotes-i-have-per-tag/71884#71884):

> Your user page now shows your score
>   per tag, under the tags section. Mouse
>   over the number to get a detailed
>   breakdown.