# Is there a way to know the number of upvotes I got on a specific tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges

Is there a way to know the number of upvotes I got on a specific tag?

I'm asking this because I'd like to know how far I'm from a tag badge :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This doesn't work anymore.**

Click on a tag, then go to the stats page.

You should be listed on each of the lists (if you have > 0 upvotes).  If you aren't in top 20, you will be at the bottom.

(I have found this to be a bit buggy, sometimes it thinks I'm a different user.)

Comment: Agreed, I've noticed it to be a little buggy as well.

Comment: agreed too, I'm really not a fan of the UI here. Thanks for the anwser!

Comment: But is it working correctly? I'm sure I've got more than 1 upvote on the rubyonrails tag, but i'm not listed :\

Comment: I think that there are caching issues. If you're not in the top 20 it can't serve the cached page (as your details have to be added). Perhaps if someone else requests the page at (about) the same time as you, you get their version of the page. *This is pure speculation.*

Comment: Could be, I seem to be bill the lizzard quite often on the 'java' tag page.

Comment: This page seems to list "total score" for a badge, not number of upvotes. If any answers received downvotes, these two values will not be equal.

Comment: Hmm, I only see the "top 20" or so for a given tag.  E.g. I know I've answered dozens of javascript questions, but I can't see how many upvotes I have.  I'm curious how many months/years/decades away from being granted a "javascript" badge I am ;-) I know on my user page, if I click a tag I've answered on, I can see the questions that I've supplied an answer for, but not a count of upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the tag and then to the stats page, your user should be listed. Example for the [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=badges&sort=stats&pagesize=50) tag.