# Show breakdown of user's reputation by source - from answers, from questions

Tags: feature-request, reputation, statistics

I think it would be useful showing the breakdown of a user's reputation on their User page.

Nothing fancy, just the percentage of reputation from questions asked and from answers given.

Comment: Id be more interested in from what tags I got the rep (on my user page)

Comment: @Ivo, ooh. That'd be cool as well.

Comment: If you're asking for rep from tags, this is now a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/finding-reputation-from-tags

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing which tags get the rep and how many visitors my question/answer brought so I can work out what cut of those sponsored tags I get. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I agree, in the meantime, there's a [GreaseMonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20896/im-not-appearing-in-the-all-time-list-for-java-is-this-a-bug/21623#21623) that allows you to see how many votes you have by tag, and [another](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13847) that gives you "badges" and stats for accepted answers by tag, the two could be combined to give a breakdown of all votes by tag fairly simply

Answer (score 1):

The reputation system on SX.Net sites is biased towards answers (for good reason, I suppose); and on SO especially, there's a [marked tendency](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187812/196834) to refrain from upvoting questions; still, for many users, this is a measure of interest. So, I whole-heartedly support this feature, with all of my ~1,100 SO reputation... :-)