# Make it possible to see a users reputation from individual tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding Reputation from Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6201/finding-reputation-from-tags)

Currently, to my knowledge, it is only possible to see a users overall reputation. Being able to see the reputation earned from individual tags would give an indication of the users diversity, and which their strong areas are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every user's profile has their tag scores down towards bottom of the page.

In the gray box of any post, click on the person's username, scroll down, and the information is between the user's vote counts and their badges.

Clicking on the vote count for any tag will open up a list of the posts which earned votes, if you're curious to see where the votes occurred.

The only caveat is if the user has hit the reputation cap on one or more days, then some of the votes may not have been applied towards his/her reputation.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the user profile and look the tag section.

You don't have the reputation but the score. By the way it serves the purpose you are asking for.